# Training the same Google AutoML Model multiple times

Tags: google-cloud-automl

Question: **Is it possible to train the same Model, from Google AutoML, multiple times?**

Problem: I have several datasets with time series data. Example:

- Dataset A: [[product1, date1, price], [product1, date2, price]]
- Dataset B: [[product2, date1, price], [product2, date2, price]]
- Dataset C: [[product3, date1, price], [product3, date2, price]]

When describing the columns in Google AutoML you can mark the data as time series data and specify the date column as the time serie. It is very important to keep in mind it is time series data. I'd think combining the datasets wouldn't be a good idea because there will be duplicate dates.

Is it possible to train the model on dataset A and after that finishes on dataset B, etc. or would you advice to combine the datasets?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine the data, I don't see how that would matter with what you are describing. Marking a column as a `Time` column has AutoML Tables [split the data](https://cloud.google.com/automl-tables/docs/prepare#time) based on that column, putting the oldest 80% as the training set, next more recent 10% as the validation set, and the most recent 10% as the test set.

If there is not enough data in your set that is distinct in the time column to split the data as 80/10/10 described above, you will want to not mark it as the Time column and instead manually split the data.

If the datasets are not related and are distinct from each other, then you would want to train individual models for each.

Comment: Hi Caleb, thanks for your response.

I was under the assumption the order (time) would matter for the underlying architecture that is used by AutoML. However, after reading the documents you provide it is clear now.

However, what I really want to ask is the following:
If I have an old model that is exported and performs descent and I have new data that I can use to train that model to become better. Is it possible to train the **old model** or do I have to combine the old data with the new data and train a **new model**?

Comment: You would need to combine data to do that. There isn't a way to provide a model plus some data and retrain.